# How do I change heading styles based on leading characters with a macro in word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I have no idea how to program using VBA but I'm slowly learning. My job wants me to format a directory export in word so things can be found in a table of contents for easy searching... by next week. There are over 1,500 pages of formatting that need to be done and that is just way too much to try to do by hand. Thankfully the tree command made it vary easy to see the levels and whatnot.

SO is there a way record a macro to do this for me automatically? Basically I need to search the entire document and

if text="           ---" then [change to heading style 4]

here's what I have after scouring the internet:

```
Sub headingStylizer()
'
' headingStylizer Macro
' Change Headings from a tree dos export
'
   If Text = "            ---" Then Selection.Style = 
ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 4")
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!!

Comment: Can't you just run a Find/ReplaceAll and assign the new formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like this should work by just doing a global find and replace

```
Sub FixTextStyle()    
    Dim head4 As Style

    Set head4 = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 4")

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        With .Replacement
            .ClearFormatting
            .Style = head4
        End With
        .Execute FindText:="            ---", ReplaceWith:="            ---", _
            Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So that worked for new text I entered but it doesn't seem to be running on the text that's already there. Any Suggestions?